# How do I deploy my website using MSBuild in TeamCity

Tags: web, deployment, teamcity

I am trying to use teamCity to deploy my Visual Studio C# solution to my website.

The difficult part is that the solution is composed of 4 project snd one website.
If I try to use MSBuild witn /P params on the solution.sln it does not upload the website, it does however compile the other 4 projects. I have tried using MSBuild and specifying the name of the website .csproject but here is the trick, I don't have a .csproject for the website because it was added to the solution as a 'new website' and not 'new web application' so there is no project file for the website itself.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Pat

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment) for ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Command Line Deployment